# How to remove unwanted tags from JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm using PHP MVC Model to build a Website, I want to use `JSON` in `Ajax` and fetch data from the database, but `response` always returns HTML tags and texts that I don't want.
Here is the Ajax code:

```
function readData() {
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/?c=filename',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    var parse = JSON.parse(response);
  }
 });
}

 readData();
```

Here is my PHP model file:

```
public function select(){
 $select_query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name");
 $select_query->execute();
 $row = $select_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 echo json_encode($row, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

and here is my PHP controller file:

```
$dashboard = new obj();  //class that contains `select` function in model file
$dashboard->select();
```

Comment: Try to call your url `http://example.com/?c=filename` only in a browser or you can use https://www.postman.com/ to check if you really receive a JSON string and not HTML. Maybe you miss some `header` in your backend

Comment: @patfreeze actually because of including view files in the controller, it always shows the HTML tags, and that's why `response` has HTML, I'm trying to get only the fetch items, not the HTML tags

Comment: `because of including view files in the controller`...well, don't do that then. Have a script which returns JSON and nothing else.

Comment: @ADyon This is how the MVC Model works, if I don't include view files in the controller it will not work

Comment: I don't know which framework you're using, but (unless it's one you made yourself) all the major ones have ways to return JSON instead of a view. In proper MVC you don't _include_ a view _into_ the controller, you _return_ a view from the controller - or if you want to return JSON, then you return JSON _instead of_ the view.

Comment: "then you return JSON instead of the view." Conceptually I would rephrase this as: You return the JSON view of the data, rather than the HTML view.

Comment: @ADyson WOW, I am confused a little bit now, I think I need more explanation because everyone told me to include view files in the controller files, like this: `include_once 'model/Msignin.php';` and after the controller stuff `include_once 'view/signin.php';` Are you telling me this is wrong?? :\

Comment: Well implementation of any design pattern is always going to be open to debate, but certainly that's not how I've ever seen MVC implemented, it sounds a bit odd

Comment: Maybe you are in the wrong way to do it like you are trying to do it. Do you use a framework?

Answer (score 1):

In your file.js add 2 args: dataType and contentType.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/?c=filename',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    var parse = JSON.parse(response);
  }
 });
```

- dataType: 'JSON'
- contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',

In your PHP file add at top this line:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

This line should avoid to catch it like html file. Use POSTMAN to test your request without Javascript. Postman can send a simple GET to

```
https://YourServerLocalOrVPStester/?c=filename
```

Perhaps, can use chrome, firefox, operaGx, or whatever you use as browers to make a simple call url too without javascript or Postman

Postman will autodetect headers and show it like JSON automatically.
[image: POSTMAN Result viewer]

If works then try it from ajax and should works too.